# Can iCloud Be Used To Exchange Data Between Users?

Tags: ios, icloud

I need to develop an App that allows a team leader to create tasks and assign them to other team members, then allow both the team leader and the members to update said tasks as needed.  Yes, I know - plenty of commercial apps do this.  But I have some very specific reasons for rolling my own.  Obviously, I need a server-based component to manage this.  Given the simplicity of the data, could I use iCloud for this?  If not, any suggestions as to what cloud vendor might be best for such a simple yet centralized data management requirement?

Comment: I don't know if this falls under what iCloud can do, but if your looking for simple cloud data, I'd check out Parse.

Answer (score 2):

iCloud cannot share between different iTunes accounts. It's purely a syncing engine and isn't designed as a generic networking/communication system.